# Where should I put properties shared between multiple projects?

Tags: c#, .net, properties

I have a .NET solution with multiple projects.  Several projects need access to a few solution-wide properties (key-value pairs).  I could put these properties in a `Settings.settings` file in one project, but as I understand the other projects won't be able to access them (right?).

Should I...

1. Put these properties in an INI file in a globally accessible shared folder like `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData/MySolutionData`
2. Put these properties in the registry?
3. Somewhere else?

**Edit:**

I forgot to mention, I'd like to able to edit this small list of properties OUTSIDE of the application, so a shared class in a common project wouldn't work.

Comment: Create a project for the common settings (implemented as static class(es) perhaps?) and add it as a reference for all the projects that need it?

Comment: Thanks for asking this, I've clarified my question above.

Answer (score 1):

I usually create an additional project for the sole purpose of handling a shared `app.config` file and make its contents available to other projects.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to place them Settings.settings, I personally would create another project with an exposed API to return the required setting.  Then you could use that dll wherever you needed and you could get creative by returning only what you need when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project which will contain an interface that defines your settings. Then create a class which implements this interface to read/write those settings. A good suggestion in another answer is to use App.Config (this would also be editable outside the application).

Using an interface to define your settings will allow you to easily develop and substitute alternative property providers as required in the future.

All projects that need to access these settings should then reference the new project to access those settings.